How to dynamically generate a complete <table> in Python with <thead> and <tbody> correctly structured?
I'm working on generating an HTML table dynamically in Python based on a pandas DataFrame. The table includes both  for headers and  for rows of data. However, I'm running into an issue where my rows () are not properly contained within a single  tag.
Here is the function I currently have:
def Analyse(df_multiselect):
    # Define the table structure with thead and tbody in one place
    table_html = """
    <table id="data-table" class="table display nowrap" width="auto">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1">المواد</th>
                <th colspan="1">الحاضرون</th>
                <th colspan="1">المتوسط الحسابي</th>
                <th colspan="1">الانحراف المعياري</th>
                <th colspan="1">التباين</th>
                <th colspan="1">أعلى نقطة</th>
                <th colspan="1">الوسيط</th>
                <th colspan="1">أدنى نقطة</th>
                <th colspan="1">المدى</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    """
    
    # Dynamically select subjects and columns
    subjects = df_multiselect.columns[11:26]  # Modify to match your actual column indices
    columns = df_multiselect.iloc[:, 11:26]

    # Calculate the statistics
    counts = columns.count()
    means = round(columns.mean(), 2)
    stdvs = round(columns.std(), 2)
    maxs = columns.max()
    mins = columns.min()
    ranges = round(maxs - mins, 2)
    variances = round(columns.var(), 2)
    medians = round(columns.median(), 2)

    # Loop through each subject to build the table rows
    for i, subject in enumerate(subjects):
        row = f"""
        <tr>
            <td>{subject}</td>
            <td>{counts.iloc[i]}</td>
            <td>{means.iloc[i]:.2f}</td>
            <td>{stdvs.iloc[i]:.2f}</td>
            <td>{variances.iloc[i]:.2f}</td>
            <td>{mins.iloc[i]}</td>
            <td>{medians.iloc[i]}</td>
            <td>{maxs.iloc[i]}</td>
            <td>{ranges.iloc[i]}</td>
        </tr>
        """
        table_html += row  # Add the current row to the table HTML

    # Close the tbody tag and the table
    table_html += "</tbody></table>"

    return table_html


# Generate the table HTML by calling Analyse
table_html = Analyse(df_multiselect)

# Generate the full HTML page to display
full_html = f"""
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row g-5 align-items-center">
                <a id="titleElement" class="btn btn-primary-soft">تحليل النتائج
                </a>
                <div class="about-image-gallery">
                    <div class="scroll-container">    
                        {table_html}
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
"""

# Display the HTML content in Streamlit using st.markdown
st.markdown(full_html, unsafe_allow_html=True)  

Problem:
This function seems to generate only one  inside the  tag, while the other  rows are placed outside the  in the resulting HTML. I need all rows to be properly encapsulated inside a single  tag.
What I’ve Tried:
I checked the loop logic and ensured all rows are being added inside the loop.
Verified the final table_html structure by printing it, and the issue persists.
Desired Output:
A valid HTML table where all  rows are correctly contained within one  tag.
Example Expected Table:
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Count</th>
            <th>Mean</th>
            <th>Std Dev</th>
            <th>Variance</th>
            <th>Max</th>
            <th>Median</th>
            <th>Min</th>
            <th>Range</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Math</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>14.56</td>
            <td>2.34</td>
            <td>5.48</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Science</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>13.42</td>
            <td>2.12</td>
            <td>4.98</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Additional rows -->
    </tbody>
</table>


If you inspect the return from Analyse() does it look correct? My guess is that it does and that the issue is related to how markdown treats whitespace in a way that is different from html. For example, try taking the trailing newline off of you row.

@JonSG thank you, i have resolved the problem by adding f"" for each line in the loop insted of general one.
'for i, subject in enumerate(subjects):
row = (
f""
f"{subject}"
f"{counts.iloc[i]}"
f"{means.iloc[i]:.2f}"
f"{stdvs.iloc[i]:.2f}"
f"{variances.iloc[i]:.2f}"
f"{mins.iloc[i]}"
f"{medians.iloc[i]}"
f"{maxs.iloc[i]}"
f"{ranges.iloc[i]}"
f""
)'

problem resolved:
The suggestion to remove trailing newlines in my row construction is a good one so i have Updated my loop to avoid extra whitespace.
# Loop through each subject to build the table rows
    for i, subject in enumerate(subjects):
        row = (
        f"<tr>"
            f"<td>{subject}</td>"
            f"<td>{counts.iloc[i]}</td>"
            f"<td>{means.iloc[i]:.2f}</td>"
            f"<td>{stdvs.iloc[i]:.2f}</td>"
            f"<td>{variances.iloc[i]:.2f}</td>"
            f"<td>{mins.iloc[i]}</td>"
            f"<td>{medians.iloc[i]}</td>"
            f"<td>{maxs.iloc[i]}</td>"
            f"<td>{ranges.iloc[i]}</td>"
        f"</tr>"
        )


Note that this "works" because it likely resolves the whitespace issue I mentioned. To illustrate, try this is a python console.  print(("foo" "bar")) replicating what you did with the multiple f-strings.

Why going through all that complexity when you can simply use pandas.DataFrame.to_html?! It will write the html from the df for you in 1 line.
